# method $_POST in a variable on php don't want to show the content

Tags: php, post

---

Hello!
Im working with PHP and I have a problem using POST

I have this on my php

```
<?php

$server = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H:i:s");
$header = apache_request_headers();
$xwap= $header['x-wap-msisdn'];


$servidor = $_POST[$server];
echo $servidor;

?>
```

but when i do this echo $servidor; the website dont show me the content.
thanks for your help!

Comment: why $_POST at all ? you have $_SERVER why not use it, assigning one variable to another is pointless

Comment: most likely because `$_POST[$server]` is not set.

Comment: because then i need to insert into a database

Comment: which as what to do with the super global $_POST ? `INSERT INTO FOO set server=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST is used to collect form data. Check $server variable if it is set. That's the best solution I think.

```
 $server = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $date = date("Y-m-d");
 $time = date("H:i:s");
 $header = apache_request_headers();
 $xwap= $header['x-wap-msisdn'];

 $servidor = (isset( $server ) ) ? $server : '' ;
 echo $servidor;
```

Comment: yes work for me, and now how can i insert that information into my database? you know ?

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name ( tbl_colname ) VALUES ( $servidor );